# Latex error with moderncv and letter

Tags: moderncv

I am using the package moderncv to create my CV. Unfortunately I can't manage to include a letter as it is done in one of the examples in the CTAN repository ([PDF file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.pdf), [TEX file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex)).

The command `\makelettertitle` seems to cause the problem. Without this command the LaTeX file compiles. With the command I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.47 \makelettertitle
```

Minimal example:

```
%% LyX 2.0.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,naustrian]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}

\firstname{My}
\familyname{Name}
\title{CV}
\address{Street}{somewhere\protect\\[0.1em] country\protect\\[0.2em]}
\mobile{+1231231231323}
\email{mail@exampl.ecom}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Section} 
\cvitem{something}{something}
\cvitem{something}{something}

\clearpage{}

\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}

\makelettertitle

Testtext.

\makeletterclosing


\end{document}
```

### Edit:

The answer solves the problem, but unfortunately only partly. The \makelettertitle command displays the address in a wrong way. I filed a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/moderncv/+bug/1063995). My solution for now is to leave out the country... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a trailing `\\` in the address. the coding is a bit odd but this seems to work.

```
 \address{Street}{somewhere\protect\\ country\protect\\\ }
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Strangly `\maketitle` can deal with the tailing `\\`. Is it possible to increase the distance to the next line as done with `[0.2em]` in my minimal example?

Comment: yes you can put the optional argument back just leave the `\ ` at the end eg `country\protect\\[1em]\ `

Comment: Thanks, that worked! (I didn't understand before why the three slashes solve the problem, now I did.)

Comment: @lumbric If you don't like 3 slashes, you can use `\\~` ;)